# How to use LIKE operator with wildcards in parameterized query in MS-Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, wildcard, prepared-statement

I am using MS Access database, where I need to pass parametrized like query.
Actually MS Access uses like in this format ... LIKE '*[par1]*' {par1 is a parameter in ms-access-query} 
So I need a way to use parametrized like query with wildcard support.
For example, if user enter 325 for par1, sql-command text in condition is ... WHERE field1 Like "*325*"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried following:

```
LIKE "*" & [par1] & "*"
```